# Automata homomorphism relation

Tags: automata

We have the following automata $A$:

[image: Automata A]

My task is to find automata $B$ and $C$ such that both of them admit a homomorphism to $A$, but $B$ is not homomorphic to $C$ and vice versa.

So far, we know that both $B$ and $C$ have to be automata accepting the same language as $A$. Furhermore, it is clear that it is language of binary words with the even number of zeroes.

My definition of automata homomorphism is the same as in [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Automata,_homomorphism_of).

Comment: Just to be sure, what is your definition of homomorphism of automata?

Comment: Crosspost with http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34144/automata-homomorphism

Comment: The definition of homomorphism given in your link does not say anything about final states and thus it is not sufficient to conclude that B and C should accept the same language.